# HTML email sending fails in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

all the HTML emails I have tried to send fails while all the text only emails are sent successfully.
Could you please tell me if I'am doing something wrong here?

Also I tried to create a TriggeredSend using HTML based Email ID via SOAP API, it provides a successful response but it stays in queued state. TriggeredSend using TextOnly Emails are getting send successfully.

Thank you.

Comment: I am glad to inform that some TriggeredSend HTML based Emails were successfully sent after several attempts. But having the concern about the consistency.

Comment: Have you checked if the email passes validation?  Can you send that email to yourself without the triggered send?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML, or a link to the html in a gist, so that can also be viewed?